# Python use Pillow locally

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I juste wanted to know if there is a way to use Pillow library without installing it, just have my Pillow folder in my project and load it from here.

I am using Python 3.5.2.

Thanks !

Comment: This is what `virtualenv` is for. Compartmentalising your projects so you dont have to globally install everything.

Answer (score 2):

You could try a *user install* in pip,

pip install --user Pillow

or a manual

python setup.py install --user

You could perhaps alternately insert the directory containing Pillow in the `sys.path` list.